# Maximum value of $|z-\sqrt3-i|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $S=\{z\in C:\overline z=iz^2\}$, then the maximum value of $|z-\sqrt3-i|^2$ on $S$ is:

I took $z$ as $x+iy$ then $S$ came out to be $\{(0,0),(0,1),(\frac{\sqrt3}{2},\frac{-1}{2}), (\frac{-\sqrt3}{2},\frac{-1}{2})\}$. Taking their distances from $(\sqrt3,-1)$, I get maximum value as $7$ but the answer is given as $9$.

Comment: You have to find distance from $(\sqrt 3,1)$ and not from $(\sqrt 3,-1)$.

Comment: @Doubtnut Thanks. Can you post this as an answer so that I could accept it? BTW, is there a quicker way to solve this question?

Comment: Actually, what you have done is absolutely correct. If I would have been at your place, I would have followed the same method :-).

Comment: @Doubtnut Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you made a mistake here:the distance you need to find is from $(\sqrt{3},1)$ and the distance is maximum for the point ($-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$) which is 3 and aquare of that is 9

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is $9$. You have$$S=\left\{0,i,\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac12i,-\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac12i\right\}$$and the square of the distance from each element of $S$ to $\sqrt3+i$ is equal to $4$, $3$, $3$, and $9$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are also asking for a quicker way in one of your comments.

You may first derive that besides $z=0$ as obvious solution, all other solutions satisfy $|z|=1$:

$$z\neq 0:\; \bar z  = i z^2 \Rightarrow |\bar z|= |z|=|z|^2\Rightarrow |z|=1$$

Now, solve
$$e^{-it} = e^{(2t+\frac{\pi}{2})i}\Leftrightarrow 3t+\frac{\pi}2=2k\pi$$

So, you get as solutions (modulo $2\pi$)

$$t=-\frac{\pi}{6},\; t=\frac{\pi}{2},\; t=\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

Rewriting $e^{it}$ in coordinate form gives the non-zero entries in your set $S$.

Comment: Thanks. From $iz^3$, how did we reach $|z|^3$?

Comment: @Ramit : Because we have $|iz^3| = |i|\cdot |z|^3$. Basically, you just take the absolute value on both sides, which does not change the LHS but simplifies the RHS.

Comment: In LHS, we can directly write $z\overline z$ as $|z|^2$ but in RHS, we just have $iz^3$. We are treating it as $|iz^3|$ because LHS is a real number, so RHS too should be a real number?

Comment: Exactly, the RHS $iz^3$ should be a real number then. But you can also make it shorter by taking the absolute value directly and using $|\bar z| = |z|$. I adjusted my answer accordingly.